# Solspace Calendar Create Event: Disallowed Key Characters Error

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

I am implementing a Solspace Calendar 1.8.5 on an EE 2.7.3 [a site](http://opteracreative.com/~mac/calendar_main/create) and get the following error when I try the built-in sample form:

> Disallowed Key Characters

Here is the code:

```
<div id="calendar_saef">
   {exp:channel:form channel="calendar_events" return="calendar_main/event/{segment_3}/updated"}
   <p><label>Title:</label><br />
   <input type="text" name="title" value="{title}" size="80" style="width: 600px;" /></p>
   {exp:calendar:date_widget}
   <p><label>Summary:</label><br />
   <textarea name="{event_summary_field_name}" rows="5" cols="65" style="width: 600px; height: 100px;">{event_summary}</textarea>
   <p><label>Location:</label><br />
   <input type="text" name="{event_location_field_name}" value="{event_location}" size="80" style="width: 600px;" /></p>
   <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
   {/exp:channel:form}
</div>
```

I would appreciate some help diagnosing this.

Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and it had to do with the title starting with a number. Expressionengine automatically converts the {title} field into a slug to use for its {url_title} field. If your title begins with a number, it can throw that error.

Comment: What does the URL after submission look like? If it contains characters that EE might deem "disallowed", it could throw that error. Also a side note: fields with `name="{event_summary_field_name}"` and `name="{event_location_field_name}"` should be `name="event_summary"` and `name="event_location"`, respectively. The Demo Templates should have this fixed in latest versions of Calendar.

Comment: Also please mention Calendar and EE versions, thanks!

Comment: I changed the field names and it corrects the problem and I am able to submit the form. Thank you. These demo templates are from the latest version of Calendar, so that needs to be updated to correct that.